# Why can't I use <execution> library with gnu++20

Tags: c++, xcode, header, include, c++20

My environment is Xcode 14.0.1 with the compiler set as below.

[compiler version setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vDjO.png)

I try to experiment with execution policy, but I cannot use any stuff inside the library.

```
#include <execution>

int main() {
    std::execution::seq; // No member named 'execution' in namespace 'std';
                         // did you mean 'exception'?
    return 0;
}
```

I can successfully include the  header so I am not sure what may be the problem

Comment: I don't think libc++ supports parallel algorithms yet? They're working on it right now, from what I heard, but for now just use TBB, which is what's under the hood of libstdc++'s implementation.

Comment: see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20, libc++ doesn't support it

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for answer! As a relative newcomer to C++, I have a question that might seem basic: I was under the impression that different C++ implementations must, at the very least, include all functionalities specified in certain standards to claim compliance. Considering that execution semantics were introduced in C++17, is it acceptable to omit their implementation and still be considered C++17 or even C++20 compliant?

Comment: @user26729 The implementations always lag behind the standards. The big 3 compilers (GCC, Clang, MSVC) implement most of C++20, but some individual features are missing here and there. Take a look at this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support *"to claim compliance"* They try to be mostly compliant, but rushing for 100% compliance doesn't give them anything. Sometimes they'd rather take their time to do it the right way (presumably Clang people consider just wrapping TBB uncool), or, in case of MSVC, they sometimes just don't bother (look at the C++23 status).

Comment: @AlanBirtles Hi Alan thanks for reference. From the page it seems that GCC libstdc++ supports it but Clang libstdc++ doesn't. Given that I set my compiler version to gnu++20, doesn't it make any difference?

Comment: libstdc++ is the name of the GCC's C++ standard library implementation, not "C++ standard library" in general. Clang's implementation is called libc++. Clang can be made to use libstdc++, as it's in general tries to be compatible with other compilers. But I don't know if Apple's version of Clang can do that. `-std=gnu++20` doesn't do that, the flag is `-stdlib=libstdc++`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't think apple clang can use libstdc++, libc++ is the only option. You'd have to install gcc if you want libstdc++

Comment: @AlanBirtles Or there's probably some way to install non-apple Clang, and use libstdc++ from that.

Comment: Understood! Thank you both for your assistance. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: One reason for slow support is that the standard library implementers all try to offer some level of ABI stability. Once they implement something it can be difficult to change without breaking the ABI so they like to make sure its correct before releasing it

Comment: @user26729 There are two major 'nix C++ standard libraries.  There are two major 'nix C++ compilers.  Both compilers can use both standard libraries.  The two libraries are called libstdc++ and libc++.  The two compilers are called clang (or clang++) and gcc (or g++).  The language features you have access to is determined by a mix of the compiler and the standard library used.  A compiler that states it is "C++20" can easiliy not have *every* C++20 feature implemented; rather, it means it may have some C++17 features replaced with C++20 ones.